# WKWebView Password autofill like Safari

Tags: ios, passwords, wkwebview, keychain

In my app I have a WKWebView to browse Internet in general, it's not tied to a specific website. I'd like to let the users to have login forms auto filled directly from the KeyChain.
When I tap the fields, in the QuickType bar I can see a "Passwords" button to open the passwords list, then I can search the website and finally the WKWebView fills the information.
I'd like to have a much more direct experience like on Safari, please see the screenshots.

My app when I tap on the textfield:

[image: WKWebView textfield tapped]

The list appearing when you tap the "Passwords" button:

[image: WKWebView passwords list]

This is Safari when tapping on the text field:

[image: Safari textfield tapped]

I don't want to fill the information via Javascript.
Is there a way to do this or is it just a Safari thing?